# Data Center Related Question is Off-Topic?

Tags: discussion

Right now I'm trying to find a home for my servers in a local data center. Can I ask about other people preferences on this matter at the serverfault? As I see now, there is no tag for the datacenter related questions.

Comment: I'd ask. I would probably answer it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  Product and service recommendations are off-topic on Server Fault, and pretty much every other Stack Exchange site.

You should probably consult with techies in your area to get recommendations on the best datacenters in your area anyway - a bunch of sysadmins from all over the world telling you their opinions on the best datacenter that's nowhere near you doesn't strike me as especially useful for your purposes.

Comment: Ok thanks, got your point. I will ask specifically about common practices (charges, security, etc.) and the 'norm' in this domain, and not about the service recommendations.

Comment: @DaveRose That's fine, but be careful - it's easy for that kind of question to get closed for being too broad or too subjective.